# SICP - Why use accumulate with cons when filter already passes back a list

Tags: scheme, sicp

In [SICP 2nd Edition](https://mitp-content-server.mit.edu/books/content/sectbyfn/books_pres_0/6515/sicp.zip/full-text/book/book-Z-H-15.html#call_footnote_Temp_154) section 2.2.3,
the authors have the following code:

```
(define (even-fibs n)
  (accumulate cons
              nil
              (filter even?
                      (map fib
                           (enumerate-interval 0 n)))))
```

My question is why did they use *accumulate* in this case? Couldn't they have got the same answer from  *filter*  without using *accumulate*?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In that section of the book, `filter`, `map`, and `enumerate-interval` are presumed to return sequences, which are conceptually distinct from lists. You can implement sequences using streams, for example, though you can implement sequences using lists too.

So, in this case, the `accumulate` with `cons` is to convert the sequence to a list.